# Implicit Naming Strategy Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am doing an Spring Boot project and I am having a problem with the Naming Strategy used by Hibernate.
As we can see in the following link: [Naming Strategies](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy). I do not know why my program has configured a physical naming strategy, whereas **I want to set an Implicit Naming Strategy**. I am using the corresponding annotations (@...) for entities, tables, id, columns... But the program interprets a physical naming strategy even so.
May someone explain me how would I change it?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idContact")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "nameContact")
    private String name;
```

Error: Unknown column 'c1_0.id_contact' in 'field list'

I do not know where could I change the naming strategy. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to either define a corresponding bean, something like:

```java
@Bean
public PhysicalNamingStrategy physicalNamingStrategy() {
  return org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl#INSTANCE; 
}
```

or set the value of `spring` configuration property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy` to `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`